# Loop over file list into dictionary; based on string

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas, filelist

I have a bunch of .csv files in a library and I would like to pull out their contents (they are NxM matrices) and put them into a dictionary. They are all the same size, and generically named {means1, means2, ...} and {trajectories1, trajectories2, ...}.

This is the bit of code i use to get the file list

```
import os
import glob
my_dir = 'insert your own datapath'
filelist = []
os.chdir( my_dir )
for files in glob.glob( "*.csv" ) :
    filelist.append(files)
```

which outputs

```
['means0.csv',
 'means1.csv',
 'means2.csv',
 'trajectories0.csv',
 'trajectories1.csv',
 'trajectories2.csv']
```

I am looking for a bit of code that will

1. Extract names; in this case "means" and "trajectories"
2. Creates a dict based on each name, i.e. `means_dict = {}`
3. Fill up the dict with the relevant .csv files. E.g. ending up with something like `means_dict['0'] = ('means0.csv')` ect.

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Could you post what you have tried, and didn't work?

Comment: use the csv module to extract the contents. Here's a [link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/) on how to use the basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really, really don't want to dynamically create dicts. Rather, use a containing dict with the key as "means", "trajectories" etc, and the values as a list of the files:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

filedict = defaultdict(list)
for filename in glob.glob( "*.csv" ) :
    result = re.match(r'([^\d]+)', filename)
    if result:
        filedict[result.group(1)].append(filename)
```

Comment: You should take group(1), group(0) is always the complete string.

Comment: In this case they are the same, but you are right, thanks - corrected.

Comment: Only just saw your answer now. Why don't I want to use dynamical dictionaries?

Comment: Yes, I would also like to know why they are bad, what defaultdict does is just initialise the dictionary if the given key does not exists, which is the same as initialising it yourself right?

Comment: I didn't say anything about dictionaries being wrong. I said you don't want to dynamically *create* them. Frankly I can't understand why anyone would even want to do so; once you've done it, how do you refer to them? How do you know how many you have or what they're called? Instead, a dictionary is an explicit container, mapping the names of things to their contents.

Comment: All a defaultdict does is automatically set a default value if a key does not exist, rather than having to check and create the empty list yourself.

Comment: Aah I understand what you mean now, you mean create the dictionary object dynamically. Yes I agree with you on that. Though you could easily store the reference in an array or dictionary, which is basically what both our answers do. (We are creating dynamically arrays which we store in a dictionary so that is why I was confused.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a dynamic dictionary like this:

```
import os
import glob
import re
my_dir = 'whatever dir'

special_filelist = dict()

filelist = []
os.chdir( my_dir )
for files in glob.glob( "*.csv" ) :
    filelist.append(files)
    fileListName = re.match(r'(.*)[0-9]', files).group(1)
    if (fileListName not in special_filelist):
        special_filelist[fileListName] = []
    special_filelist[fileListName].append(files)


print special_filelist
```

which in my own test gave this result:

```
{'test': ['test2.csv', 'test0.csv', 'test1.csv'], 'else': ['else0.csv', 'else1.csv']}
```

Comment: That worked beautifully and right out of the box. Thanks.